# segmentedControl and TextView refresh/reload - xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, selection, uisegmentedcontrol

I've got the following code which is a segmentedControl for a language selection option. Case 0 is for English and case 1 is for Greek which is then passed to a `UITextView`. The problem is that every time I press the button for case 1 or 0 I have to go back to the previous view controller which is a table view controller and come back to the "detailViewController" for the correct language to be displayed. Is there a way for this to be done without switching back and forth between the view controllers? Something like a small animation or a refresh or a reload method for `UITextView`.

```
 int a;

- (IBAction)languageSeg:(id)sender {

switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {

 case 0:

 a=0;

        break;

    case 1:
        a=1;

        break;

    default:

        break;
}
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:YES];


UIImage *saladImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"salad.jpg"];

UIImage *fishImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fish.jpg"];

 [textDetail setScrollEnabled:YES];

 [textDetail setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 190)];


//Switch the UIImages and UILabel based on item



switch (itemNumber) {
    case 0:
        itemName.text = @"Salad";
        itemPic.image = saladImage;
        self.title = @"Salads";

        if (a==0){

            textDetail.text = @"description in english";

        }

        if (a==1){

            textDetail.text = @"description in greek";
        }

        break;


      case 1:

       // etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the text for the textView in the languageSeg: method the same way you set it initially in viewWillAppear:

I would create a separate method that handles the language switch, then call that method from both viewWillAppear and languageSeg and anywhere else you need it.

For example, your language setter method would include the code currently at the bottom of viewWillAppear:

```
- (void) languageSetter {

    switch (itemNumber) {
       case 0:
            itemName.text = @"Salad";
            itemPic.image = saladImage;
            self.title = @"Salads";

            if (a==0){
                textDetail.text = @"description in english";
            }
            if (a==1){
               textDetail.text = @"description in greek";
            }
      break;

      case 1:
        // etc.
      break;

      default:
      // default case
      break;
    }
}
```

Then your viewWillAppear: method would look like this:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     [super viewWillAppear:YES];
     UIImage *saladImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"salad.jpg"];
     UIImage *fishImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fish.jpg"];

     [textDetail setScrollEnabled:YES];
     [textDetail setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 190)];

     [self languageSetter];
}
```

And your languageSeg: method would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)languageSeg:(id)sender {

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {

       case 0:
           a=0;
           break;

       case 1:
           a=1;
           break;

       default:
           break;
    }

    [self languageSetter];
}
```

A lot of implementation would be dependent on how the rest of your code is set up and your individual needs, but this is the general idea.

Comment: perfect! thanks!! it works, though i had to transfer the uiimage back to -(void)languageSetter because it was not recognized.. also when i go back to the table view and back to the viewController the segmented control does not "remember" my previous choice but the text is already switch to that. for example when i press greek both (greek description and greek button are "on"). but when i go back and forth again the button in highlighted on english and the text is in greek.. how do i make segmented control remember my choice?? thanks again!!

Comment: glad I could help!  Please mark the answer as correct when you have a chance.  To make the segmented control display correctly, you could keep track of the user's selection through NSUserDefaults, or you could check which text is in textDetail in viewWillAppear:, and then set the segmented control index appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I have an app with a language selector, and I use NSUserDefaults. Works like a charm. 
In the view controller with the picker:

```
- (IBAction)languageSeg:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

       [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"language"];
        break;

    case 1:

        [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"language"];
        break;

    default:

        break;
}
}
```

And In the `vieWillAppear` in the viewController displaying the language:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults integerForKey:@"language"] == 0) {
        textDetail.text = @"description in english";

    }else{
        textDetail.text = @"description in greek";
    }
```

Now, in the `viewDidLoad` method, you need to give it a default value if there is no value set by the user yet, like this: (again in your view controller displaying the setting, not the picker view.)

```
 if (![defaults integerForKey:@"language"]) {
        [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"language"];
    }

textDetail.text = @"description in english";
```

Comment: still the same.. i have to go back to the table view and select the cell in order for the language to be set. my problem wasnt that it did not change but i wouldnt have to go back and forth to the controlers to see the effect.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `switch (itemNumber)` got called?

If it's in methods like `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` etc, it will only be called when this view shows up.

You may need to extract this part as a method, and also put it in `(IBAction)languageSeg:(id)sender`. For example:

```
- (void)updateView
{
    switch (itemNumber) {
    case 0:
    itemName.text = @"Salad";
    itemPic.image = saladImage;
    self.title = @"Salads";

    if (a==0){

        textDetail.text = @"description in english";

    }

    if (a==1){

        textDetail.text = @"description in greek";
    }

    break;


  case 1:

   // etc.
}
```

Then call this method in `viewDidLoad` and 
`languageSeg:` after switch block.

Comment: its in the view will appear..can you give me an exaple please?